# Trying to create a new model based off of a rails variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have tagged words that are supposed to represent stock names(eg: '$SBUX'). I am trying to make a model for each of these names. Any time a stock is tagged I want to create a new model with just the 'stockname'. I think I am basically asking is there a way to turn an instance variable into a new `Stock` every time a new instance of that variable is created. So in pseudocode.

```
@taggedword = Stock.new.stockname
```

Note: I have two models Stock and User. They have a has_many relationship. I am trying to associate a tagged word with creating a new `Stock`. Stock is the model.

Comment: How many stocks are in the world? Are you sure you want to create a model for each them. You should rather create a stock model, and then a has many association between the stock and the class which will be tagged with a certain stock. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html is a good resource to start with.

Comment: The only problem I see is I need people to be able to follow a stock and get information on it. I'm not sure how I would implement my relationship model without different stock models. I realize it would be a large base considering there is hundreds of thousands of stocks, but I'm not sure another way to do it. Now I guess I could make feed a model and create a way to make that person subscribe to feeds specifically tied to that tag to cut down on the server load.

Comment: Check out my answer and see if it helps. Rails has very good resources at http://guides.rubyonrails.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would want is a has_many to a has_many association from user to stocks and create a table for the relation stocks_user. This way a user can follow many stocks, and a stock can have many followers (users in my example). Read more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

users.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :stocks
```

stocks.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

new table for the relations.

```
create_table :stocks_users do |t|
  t.belongs_to :stock
  t.belongs_to :user
end
```

This way you can get which stocks a user is following, and how many users follow a certain stock etc.

Comment: I have the follow part down. I just need a way for the users to create stocks unless I pull a master list from the Yahoo csv file. Any time a new stock is tagged it should create a new stock. I just realized now what you said though. I do have two models only stocks and users with the `has_many` relationship. I must have worded it funny. I don't want a model for each stock just a new stock to be created every time a stock that isn't in the database is tagged.

Comment: I figured it out. Sorry I didn't explain it well.

Comment: `@stock = Stock.create(symbol: @moneytag.name.upcase)`